# What does "Even when he's wrong, he's right" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, donnie-brasco

In *Donnie Brasco* (1997), Lefty says to Donnie:

> I'm always right. A wise guy's always right. **Even when he's wrong,
>   he's right**.

This line is strangely close to this [Scarface line](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62081)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of phrase or line is a bastardization of the phrase of two rules of the king. The first rule is that the king is always right. The second rule is that if the king is wrong, follow rule number one. You do not argue with someone who could kill you. You just do what they say to do.

Answer (score 0):

### It just means "You don't argue with a wise guy".

This is a pretty common expression, it merely states that whatever you might say there is no point in getting into a discussion about the subject.

The "wise guy" either won't listen, will not entertain the idea that he's wrong, or that you run the risk of being smacked down hard because you *were* right and he doesn't like being told that he was wrong.